# ionic - cross-origin read blocking (CORB) - request returns 200 but no response data

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework, cors

This is my first ever Ionic app and I'm on version 4 with angular 7.2.2.

So I'm facing some dificult on requesting an API which **receives and responds with text format.**

This is my code (which I copied from a tutorial).

```
login(email: String, password: String) {

  let formData = {user:'myuser',pass:'mypass'}

  return this.http.post(this.env.API_URL+'/login', JSON.stringify(formData), {responseType:'text'}).pipe(
    tap(token => {
      this.storage.set('token', token)
      .then(
        () => {
          console.log('Token Stored: ' + token);
        },
        error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
      );
      this.token = token;
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      return token;
    }),
  );

}
```

So, the request is being fired and returning HTTP 200, but Preview and Response tabs (chrome inspector) shows "This request has no response data available".

The log `console.log('Token Stored: ' + token);` is being fired but shows empty token `Token Stored:`

Also, console shows a warning with:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://...site.net/api/login
with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768
for more details.
```

As I'm a newbie with typescript and Ionic, I have no idea on how to deal with this.

Someone can help?

Comment: Is that the only message the browser logs? Does it not also log a message about a missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin header? What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response? And what does the actual response look like? Inspect it in the Network pane in devtools? Is it actually JSON? And exactly what is your code doing in the end with that response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker yes that's the only message... the request is returning HTTP 200 OK but no response data... In postman I can see the API is working fine and returning text format with JSON inside

Comment: in postman I can see API turning text format with JSON inside `{"token":"mytokenhere"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by opening chrome with disabled security

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=""
```